# Sidekiq in dockerised rails application on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a docker compose file with this content.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_USER: user
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'

  web:
    image: production_image
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db
      - redis
      - sidekiq
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  redis:
```

In this to run sidekiq, we run `bundle exec sidekiq` in the current directory. This works on my local machine in development environment. But on AWS EC2 container, I am sending my `docker-compose.yml` file and running `docker-compose up`. But since the project code is not there, sidekiq fails. How should I run sidekiq on EC2 instance without sending my code there and using docker container of my code only in the compose file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two important things you need to do are to remove the `volumes:` declaration that gets the actual application code from your local filesystem, and upload your built Docker image to some registry.  Since you're otherwise on AWS, [ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/what-is-ecr.html) is a ready option; public Docker Hub will work fine too.

Depending on how your Rails app is structured, it might make sense to use the same image with different commands for the main application and the Sidekiq worker(s), and it might work to just make it say

```
sidekiq:
  image: production_image
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
```

Since you're looking at AWS anyways you should also consider the possibility of using hosted services for data storage (RDS for the database, Elasticache for Redis).  The important thing is to include the locations of those data stores as environment variables so that you can change them later (maybe they would default to `localhost` for developer use, but always be something different when deployed).

You'll also notice that my examples don't have `links:`.  Docker provides an internal DNS service for containers to find each other, and Docker Compose arranges for containers to be found via their service key in the YAML file.

Finally, you should be able to test this setup locally before deploying it to EC2.  Run `docker build` and `docker-compose up` as needed; debug; and if it works then `docker push` the image(s) and launch it on Amazon.

```
version: '3'
volumes: *volumes_from_the_question
services:
  db: *db_from_the_question
  redis: *redis_from_the_question

  sidekiq:
    image: 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp/sidekiq:1.0
    environment:
      - PGHOST: db
      - REDIS_HOST: redis

  app:
    image: 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp/app:1.0
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - PGHOST: db
      - REDIS_HOST: redis
```